# How to remove empty cells and reduce columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table, that looks roughly like this:

```
| variable | observer1 | observer2 | observer3 | final | 
| -------- | --------- | --------- | --------- | ----- |
| case1    |           |           |           |       |
| var1     | 1         | 1         |           |       |
| var2     | 3         | 3         |           |       |
| var3     | 4         | 5         |           | 5     |
| case2    |           |           |           |       |
| var1     | 2         |           | 2         |       |
| var2     | 5         |           | 5         |       |
| var3     | 1         |           | 1         |       |
| case3    |           |           |           |       |
| var1     |           | 2         | 3         | 2     |
| var2     |           | 2         | 2         |       |
| var3     |           | 1         | 1         |       |
| case4    |           |           |           |       |
| var1     | 1         |           | 1         |       |
| var2     | 5         |           | 5         |       |
| var3     | 3         |           | 3         |       |
```

Three colums for the observers, but only two are filled.
First I want to compute the IRR, so I need a table that has two columns without the empty cells like this:

```
| variable | observer1 | observer2 |
| -------- | --------- | --------- |
| case1    |           |           |
| var1     | 1         | 1         |
| var2     | 3         | 3         |
| var3     | 4         | 5         |
| case2    |           |           |
| var1     | 2         | 2         |
| var2     | 5         | 5         |
| var3     | 1         | 1         |
| case3    |           |           |
| var1     | 2         | 3         |
| var2     | 2         | 2         |
| var3     | 1         | 1         |
| case4    |           |           |
| var1     | 1         | 1         |
| var2     | 5         | 5         |
| var3     | 3         | 3         |
```

I try to use the tidyverse packages, but I'm not sure. Some 'ifelse()' magic may be easier.
Is there a clean and easy method to do something like this? Can anybody point me to the right function to use? Or just to a keyword to search for on stackoverflow? I found a lot of methods to remove whole empty columns or rows.

Edit: I removed the link to the original data. It was unnecessary. Thanks to Lamia for his working answer.

Comment: Can you include in your post a `dput` of your data object? It is not clear from your description how your data is structured.

Comment: This seems like an awful data format where you're separating data by "empty" rows with `case1`, `case2`, etc. That's *not* a tidy format. You should consider saving data for every case in a `list` of `data.frame`/`tibble`s. Or alternatively `nest` data for every case.

Comment: Yes, the data is not tidy at all. I try to get it in a more tidy format. I have added a link to the real data (minus a few unneccesary columns). It' a german file for a meta-analysis. I translated the column names, the variable names are still in german and the studies are divided by the word 'Studie', not 'case' like in my example.

Comment: Why don't you include it directly in your question, instead of in a link? If it is too big, you can include only a portion of it.

Comment: I includet just the first study in the question. To see the structure of the data you have to see multiple studies - to see only two different observer columns are filled per study. But that would be too long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of your 3 columns `observer1`, `observer2` and `observer3`, you sometimes have 2 non-`NA` values, 1 non-`NA` value, or 3 `NA` values.
If you want to merge your 3 columns, you could do:

```
res = data.frame(df$coding,t(apply(df[paste0("observer",1:3)],1,function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1:2])))
```

The `apply` function will return for each row the 2 non-`NA` values if there are 2, one non-`NA` value and one `NA` if there is only one value, and two `NA`s if there is no data in the row.
We then put this result in a dataframe with the first column (`coding`).